# C++ Void and Constructor Method Problem with Loops

Tags: c++

I am having a problem on the console game I am making. How can I decrease the health of the character or enemy with loopings? My code goes like this by the way for example:

```
class RPG_Scene_Battle {
public:
  RPG_Scene_Battle(float ini_health) : health (ini_health){};
  float getHealth()
  {
      return health;

      }
  void setHealth(float rpg_val){ health = rpg_val;};

private:
  float health;
};

float conductDamage(RPG_Scene_Battle rpg_tr, float damage) {
  rpg_tr.setHealth(rpg_tr.getHealth() - damage);
  return rpg_tr.getHealth();
}
```

how can I do a do while loop to decrease the player and enemy's hp without returning the method? because returning the method `conductDamage` under the do loop would return the same value and not decrease constantly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `conductDamage` function uses a new copy of the `RPG_Scene_Battle` object on each invocation (the parameter is passed by value), you need to pass a reference to the object instead. Simplest way of doing this is to change the signature of the function to

```
float conductDamage(RPG_Scene_Battle &rpg_tr, float damage)
```

Comment: would it not copy the same function when we loop it?

Comment: In the loop I assume you pass the same RPG_Scene_Battle object to conductDamage(), if you don't use pass-by-reference as described above the private object field `health` is only modified for the copy of the object - not the original object. This leads to the same value being returned on each invocation of conductDamage().

Comment: @Angel: Using a pass-by-reference speeds up the application tremendously too. Due to not copying all data into a new part of memory. So it is almost always the better choice for games that uses a loop.